# Mapbox Polyline too complex, maybe?

Tags: mapbox, polyline

I am using Mapbox API to locate two gps locations and draw a polyline between them.  The code that I have written works...sometimes.

It seems that if the two locations are physically close to each other it works more often than not, but if the two points are further away then it doesn't work more often than not, but I can't duplicate the results consistently.  My working theory right now is that the polyline gets too complex for the API to decode.  Is there a way to simplify a polyline or request a simpler one in the first place?

I've marked the line in the code below that is problematic.  Does anyone have any ideas why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't???

If it matters, my ultimate goal with this is generating a static map image that will be used in a report, so I'm not really worried about bandwidth or efficiency, I just need the image to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
     <script src="js/jquery.fileDownload.js"></script>

    <script>
    
        //Declare Variables
        var token = "myuniquetoken"; 
        var longitude;
        var latitude;
        var longitude2;
        var latitude2;
        var polyline;
        
        //When first Get GPS Button is Pressed
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnGetGPS").click(function(){
                var address = $("#address").val();
                var addressstring = address.replace(" ", "%20");
                var url = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + addressstring + ".json?access_token=" + token;
                
                var jqxhr = $.getJSON( url, function(data) {
                    
                    longitude = data["features"][0]["center"][0];
                    latitude = data["features"][0]["center"][1];
                    
                    $("#gpslong").text(longitude);
                    $("#gpslat").text(latitude);
                                    
                    var mapPinUrl = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/pin-s-l+000(" + longitude + "," + latitude + ")/" + longitude + "," + latitude + ",14/500x300?access_token=" + token;
                    
                    $('#mapDiv').html('<img id="mapImg" src=' + mapPinUrl +' />');
                    $('#secondlocation').show();
                                    
                                    
                  });
            }); 
        });

        //When second Get GPS Button is Pressed
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnGetGPS2").click(function(){
                var address2 = $("#address2").val();
                var addressstring2 = address2.replace(" ", "%20");
                var url2 = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + addressstring2 + ".json?access_token=" + token;
                var jqxhr2 = $.getJSON( url2, function(data) {
                    
                    longitude2 = data["features"][0]["center"][0];
                    latitude2 = data["features"][0]["center"][1];
                    
                    $("#gpslong2").text(longitude2);
                    $("#gpslat2").text(latitude2);
                
                
                //Get a polyline
                                
                var polyURL = "https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/" + longitude + "," + latitude + ";" + longitude2 + "," + latitude2 + "?access_token=" + token;
                console.log(polyURL);
                
                var polyJSON = $.getJSON( polyURL, function(data2) {
                    
                    polyline = data2["routes"][0]["geometry"];
                    console.log(polyline);
                    
                    //////////////////The next line is the problematic one.//////////////////
                    
                    var mapRoute = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/static/pin-s-a+9ed4bd(" + longitude + "," + latitude + "),pin-s-b+000(" + longitude2 + "," + latitude2 + "),path-5+f44-0.5(" + polyline + ")/auto/500x300?access_token=" + token;
                    console.log(mapRoute);
                    
                    $('#mapDiv2').html('<img id="mapImg" src=' + mapRoute +' />');
                    
                  });
                
                  });
            }); 
        });
        
    </script>
</head>

<body>
   Enter an address (i.e. 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC 20500):</br>
    <input id="address"/></br>
    <button id="btnGetGPS" type="button">Get GPS</button>
    <div id = "gpslong"></div>
    <div id = "gpslat"></div>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    <div id="secondlocation" style="display:none">
        Enter a second location:
        <input id="address2"/></br>
        <button id="btnGetGPS2" type="button">Get GPS</button>
        <div id = "gpslong2"></div>
        <div id = "gpslat2"></div>
        <div id="mapDiv2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm leaving this question up and proving the answer that someone helped me discover in hopes of helping other people in the future.
.
The problem was that the polyline I was getting in the first API request contained special characters like `,~,|, etc.  When I tried to use that same string in the second API request, those special characters were sometimes causing problems.  I added the line of code below to scrub out those special characters and replace them with safe ASCII.
.
polyline = encodeURIComponent(polyline);